# need help compiling ccfits library in c++ on windows

Tags: c++, cmake, compilation, fits

I try to compile CCfits in visual studio project (windows) but i dont arrive to do it. CCfits need cfitsio but he dont find it during the compilation. i already compiled cfitsio following this step (https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/FTP/software/fitsio/c/README.win) and i ran the test executable.

so i have:

- ./libs/cfitsio
- ./libs/cfitsio.build
- ./libs/ccfits
- ./libs/ccfits.build

i try to compile ccfits using following this steps (https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/fitsio/CCfits/html/installation.html).

I opened a cmd in the directory ./libs/ccfits.build and i try this commande: `cmake.exe -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:\...\libs\cfitsio.build\Release ..\ccfits`

but an error occurred:

`CMake Error at FindCFITSIO.cmake:30 (MESSAGE): Could not find the CFITSIO library Call Stack (most recent call first): CMakeLists.txt:25 (find_package)`

i don't understand why. Can someone help me please?

Comment: Aside from building `cfitsio` library, you need to **install** it. E.g. with `cmake.exe --build . --config Release --target install`. And when configure `ccfits`, value of `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` should contain **installation prefix** of `cfitsio`. [installation guide](https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/fitsio/CCfits/html/installation.html) has even more detailed explanations: "This path should be set to the root directory of your CFITSIO installation, from which it will look in \lib and \include subdirectories for the library and header files respectively."

Comment: @Tsyvarev thank you for your time. Yes i didn't install it thank you. But i still have the same problem. When i enter cmake.exe -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\CFITSIO ..\CCfits this return the same error.

Comment: I see, you have specified `C:\Program Files (x86)\CFITSIO` as an installation prefix of cfitsio. So, do you **actually** have files `C:\Program Files (x86)\CFITSIO\include\fitsio.h` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\CFITSIO\lib\cfitsio.lib`?

Comment: @Tsyvarev yes i have them. i tried to compile it using the cmake executable and put this two path into CFITSIO_INCLUDE_DIR and CFITSIO_LIBRARY variables. After i enter the command: cmake.exe --build . --config Release --target install but that return to me "fatal error LNK 1181:cannot open input file  'Release\CCfits.lib'" Indeed they are no any CCfits.lib in Release... snif

Comment: Probably, something wrong in `ccfits` itself. E.g. they created a shared library `CCfits` but forgot to export symbols from it (`dllexport`). You could report a bug for the project... however I am unsure whether they have a bugtracker.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thank you for your time. Yes i dont think they have bugtracker... i think i will just do a library by myself based of cfitsio

Comment: You may also consider use a package manager, I find that vcpkg have already has the ports you need:https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/tree/master/ports/ccfits

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin really thank you. I dont arrive yet to make work ccfits but now im able to use cfitsio and i can directly ask about missing link on github.

Comment: So is your problem gone? How do you fixed it?

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin not yet but in progress. i had directly posted problems that i encounter in the github of vcpkg.  Im now able to use cfitsio but not yet ccfits.